# abort output and return to prompt in shell mode

Tags: emacs

If I give a command in shell-mode that produces lot of output then emacs takes a lot of time inserting it in the *shell* buffer, long after the command has completed execution.

Invariably, I had made some small mistake in the command, e.g. forgot `-n` on `sed` command . On a `rxvt` window pressing `control-c` takes me back to shell prompt immediately. Not so in `emacs` where `control-c control-c` kills the inferior process but if the process has completed execution it does not `emacs` to abort output.

Is there a way to do that? I am using `GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (i686-pc-cygwin, GTK+ Version 2.24.10) of 2012-05-16 on moufang`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave emacs running and just return to a shell briefly you can use `<Ctrl+Z>` (and then type `fg` tor return) otherwise to quit quickly it would be `<Ctrl+X>` followed by `<Ctrl+C>`.

Comment: I meant a command that I give in `*shell-mode*`, I want to return to the prompt in the `*shell*` buffer